# I want to change the url using rewrite in nginx

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, server

Substitute MYDOMAIN with "http://www.example.com" in the question. Due to lack of reputation, I am not able to post URL's in the question. I want to change my url from "MYDOMAIN/?category=something" to "MYDOMAIN/something" how can i do this using nginx rewrite function ?

I have tried with following things:

I have tried with following two methods in nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file.

```
rewrite ^(/?category=chaplincomdey) /comedy/charliechaplin.html permanent;
location = /?category=chaplincomdey {
        rewrite MYDOMAIN/comedy/charliechaplin permanent;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/488444/nginx-rewrite-convert-querystring-to-path/488480#488480.

```
location / {
    if($args_category) {
        return 301 /$arg_category;
    }
}
```